# Errors aren't showing when validation failed

Tags: php, laravel, validation

`dump($request->all());` function doesn't execute If validation is failed. Instead I have redirect to previous page. That's OK. But... An errors list doesn't appear and `<div class="alert alert-danger">` row missing in html code. Session is started, I see `laravel_session` in cookies. Why the condition `@if (count($errors)>0)` doesn't execute?

**GuestController.php**

```
class GuestController extends Controller
{

// Add comments
public function store(Request $request){

    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'message' => 'required'
    ];

    $this->validate($request, $rules);

    dump($request->all());
```

**Kernel.php**

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    ];
```

**Fragment from layout**

```
            @if (count($errors)>0)
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul >
                    @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li> {{ $error }} </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif
```

Comment: which Laravel version do you use

Comment: @lewis4u, I use 5.5.3 version

Comment: please do format your question properly

Comment: Show us the code where you're redirecting back. You're probably missing `->withErrors($validator->errors())`

Comment: This is not Laravel version 5.5.3... by default your middleware array should look like this:     protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
    ];

Answer (score 0):

i think you are doing wrong in Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        // dd($request);
        $this->validate($request,[
          'name' => 'required',
          'email' => 'required',
          'message' => 'required'
        ]);
        Session::flash('success','Successfully saved');
    }
```

In your View create.blade.php file

```
@if(Session::has('success'))

    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <strong>Success::</strong> {{ Session::get('success') }}
    </div>

@endif

@if(count($errors) > 0)

    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong>Errors:</strong>
        <ul>
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>

@endif
```